# Cat 5e keystone or 8P8C/RJ45 terminating a Cat 6 cable?

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable

I'm about to run about 30 m of Cat 6, but I'm struggling to find local vendors that supply keystone modules (or 8P8C/RJ45 connectors, for that matter) that are explicitly labeled as Cat 6. I'm under the impression that the differences between Cat 5e and Cat 6 primarily pertain to the cable itself (properties such as twist rate) rather than whatever terminates it, and that keystones and 8P8C/RJ45 plugs should be interchangeable with 5e ones. Am I correct, or should I keep looking for explicitly Cat 6-rated components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is no difference. The only difference in jacks to pay attention to would be the wiring standards (568 A or B). The main difference between the two standards is twist count, shielding and the separation of the pairs within the cable. Both cat5e and cat6 keystone jacks fulfill the same requirements:

> Meets FCC subpart 68 requirements Jack contacts, phosphor Bronze alloy
> with a minimum 50 microinch gold
> plating over nickel.
>
> Insertion life -- 750 cycles minimum UL listed

Answer (score 1):

I've used Cat5e keystone jacks on Cat6 cable runs before and the signal/speeds were fine.  But you *can* get CAT6-specific keystones - check out [CablesToGo's selection](http://search.cablestogo.com/?vno=24&N=0&Ntt=cat6+keystone).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll leave the question as unanswered for now in the hope that someone has something definitive to say.

Comment: Try to get the CAT6 jacks if you can.  It's really hard (and is a bad idea?) to stuff the larger CAT6 cable into (properly anyways) a CAT5e jack...

Comment: The cable itself is only marginally thicker, and if you push so much sheathing in that you notice a difference in how it sits then you'd have the same problem on a cat6 jack too and you are wiring the jack wrong. Only the tip of the sheath should enter into the jack itself. If you're pushing more than that in then you are creating potential connection problems as it can put stress on the termination points that can cause them to lift in time, especially if the punch down was not done well.

Comment: The sheath *does* have to make it all the way to the sheath crimp point though.  It can be pretty hard to even get that far.

Comment: There's no sheathing crimp point on keystone jacks. Wall-plate installs shouldn't have cable-tug problems, and surface-mount boxes usually have the sheathing crimp on them (and it often sucks).